# How can I get the current session timezone in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I know that I can the session timezone with

```
SET TIMEZONE TO 'CET';
```

But is there a way to get it back? I want something like

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE::timestamptz, SYSDATE::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', SYSDATE::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'CET';
```

which I would expect to return

```
UTC| ... 12:23:55.963747 | ... 12:23:55.963747+00 | ... 12:23:55.963747+00 | ... 12:23:55.963747+01
```

Is there a way to get it? I don't see any functio CURRENT_TIMEZONE or GET_TIMEZONE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`CURRENT_SETTING('timezone')`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CURRENT_SETTING.html) to get it or `SHOW TIMEZONE`;

```
select current_setting('timezone'), sysdate, sysdate::timestamptz, sysdate::timestamptz at time zone 'utc', sysdate::timestamptz at time zone 'cet';
UTC 2021-03-19 12:48:09.989592  2021-03-19 12:48:09.989592+00   2021-03-19 12:48:09.989592  2021-03-19 13:48:09.989592
```